# ¿.toUpperCase() o .equalsIgnoreCase() en variables tipo char?

Tags: java, variables, condiciones

```
public void setGenero(char genero) {
    System.out.println("Ingrese el genero");
    genero=teclado.next().charAt(0);
    if (genero.equalsIgnoreCase().chatAt(0)=='H'){ //Aqui esta el error. En el equalsIgnoreCase()
        this.genero=genero;
    }
}
```

Este es el mensaje que aparece cuando quiero correr el programa:

> java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:      Cannot invoke
>   equalsIgnoreCase() on the primitive type char

En este codigo tengo una variable de tipo `char` a la cual busco que solo se le pueda ingresar M (De mujer) o H (De hombre) para especificar el genero de una persona. Pero el usuario puede ingresar esas letras en mayusculas o en minusculas y quiero que el programa las ignore.
Tambien lo he intentado con el `.toUpperCase()` pero me sale el mismo error.

He visto que el `.equalsIgnoreCase()` y el `.toUpperCase()` se usan en variables de tipo `String`  pero tambien que funciona con los `Char`. Mi profesor de Programacion nos enseño eso pero no recuerdo el codigo.

Comment: Y cual es el error?

Comment: Una posible solucion seria utilizar String, no necesariamente tiene que ser un dato CHAR recuerda que equalsIgnoreCase() es mas exclusivos de los String, otra cosa que error te da men.

Comment: @gbianchi 
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot invoke equalsIgnoreCase() on the primitive type char
Este es el error

Comment: El error debe ir siempre en la pregunta. Mira por favor [ask]. Usa el boton [edit] y agrega el error ahi. Mas alla de eso, el error es claro, no existe ese metodo para chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo primero, en tu pequeño bloque de código tienes varios errores, en concreto en esta linea:

```
if (genero.equalsIgnoreCase().chatAt(0)=='H')
```

- El tipo char es primitivo, no un objeto por lo que no puede ser desreferenciado (dereferenced). Partiendo de este punto todo lo que intentas hacer con el ya esta mal.
- No es cha**t**At, es **charAt**.
- No tiene sentido que hagas `charAt(0)` a una variable tipo `char`, ya que el `charAt` lo usas en un `String` para conseguir un `char` especifico
- El `equalsIgnoreCase()` no lo estarías usando correctamente ni aun que se tratase de un `String`. La forma correcta sería `genero.equalsIgnoreCase("h")` en caso de que `genero` fuese `String`.

Dicho esto, si quitas el `.equalsIgnoreCase()` y `charAt(0)` hubiera sido valido, `if (genero.equalsIgnoreCase().chatAt(0)=='H')` → `if (genero=='H')` pero no te compararía en caso de minúsculas

---

### Comparar chars

La forma de comparar chars es mucho mas simple:

**Nota:** Las comillas simples son importantes, indican que es un char y no una cadena.

**SI** diferencia minúsculas y mayúsculas (Case sensitive):

```
genero == 'h'
```

Aquí, hay un trick para comparar chars y asegurarnos que lo compara bien a pesar de minúsculas y mayúsculas. Pasar el `char` a mayúsculas:

```
Character.toUpperCase(genero) == 'H' //Pasamos el char a mayus y comparamos con la letra mayúscula
```

o minúsculas:

```
Character.toLowerCase(genero) == 'h' //Pasamos el char a minus y comparamos con la letra minúsculas
```

---

### Convertir a String para comparar

Si realmente quieres usar `equalsIgnoreCase()` tendrás que pasar el `char` a `String`

```
if(String.valueOf(genero).equalsIgnoreCase("h")){
  System.out.println("Es H");
}
```

repito, que no hace falta el `charAt` por que `genero` ya es un `char`

Answer (score -1):

Ahí te lo esta diciendo claro no puedes invocar ese metodo, en variables del tipo char la solucion vendria en usar datos tipo String.

Aqui un ejemplo.

```
public class SeleccionaGenero {

private String genero, hombre, mujer;

       public SeleccionaGenero(){

            this.genero = "";
            this.hombre = "hombre";
            this.mujer = "mujer"
         }

public void setGenero(String g) {

    this.genero = g;

    System.out.println("Ingrese el genero");

    String datosUser = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese su genero H/M"); //No era 
     necesario pero me gusta trabajar mas con estas clases de interaccion con el usuario, 
      que con la consola.

    if (datosUser.equalsIgnoreCase("h")){ //Aqui ignora que sea mayuscula o minuscula.
        this.genero = hombre;
    }
    else{

      this.genero =  mujer;
    }

}

  public String getGenero(){

         return this.genero;
      }
}
```

Comment: No respondas varias veces la misma pregunta (no es la primera vez que lo haces). Por favor, revisa como funciona el sitio mirando el [tour]. Otra cosa, el usuario usa la consola, mas alla de tu recomendacion, usa tambien la consola. Si es una app de consola, no va a poder usar ese control que le decis. Y explica tu codigo, por mas que parezca simple, no se entiende que hace ni corrige el problema del usuario. mira tambien [answer]