# "SI" o "si" toma con TRUE pero "Seguir" toma como FALSE

Tags: java

Pregunta al usuario si quiere seguir jugando, toma la primera letra de la respuesta, y si es una "s" o una "S" el booleano da TRUE, pero por algún motivo si en vez de escribir el usuario SI o si escribe "seguir" devuelve FALSE y sale. La idea es que aunque responda algo con espacios, sólo tome la primera letra.

la idea es permitir: SI, si, seguir, Seguir, s (cualquier palabra que comience por la letra "S" o "s").

```
System.out.println("¿Volver a jugar?(si/no): ");
volverjugar = teclado.nextLine();
String primera=volverjugar.substring(0, 1);
boolean seguir;
seguir = (primera == "s" || primera == "S");
System.out.println(seguir);
```

Comment: que tal si haces `seguir = primera.toUpperCase().equals("S")`

Comment: En Java tienes que usar `equals` para comparar cadenas. Intenta así: **`seguir = ( primera.equals("s") || primera.equals("S") );`**

Comment: _cualquier palabra que comience por la letra "S" o "s"_ ¿Salmon?¿submarino?. Por que no comparas el `String` completo con `.equalsIgnoreCase()`? Relacionado: [¿.toUpperCase() o .equalsIgnoreCase() en variables tipo char?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/293966/touppercase-o-equalsignorecase-en-variables-tipo-char/294258#294258)

Comment: Salmón y submarino también serían true. xD no pongo yo las condiciones.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

En Java tienes que usar `equals` para comparar si **el contenido** de dos cadenas son iguales. El operador `==` sólo será verdadero si los **objetos** son iguales, o sea, si apuntan a la misma referencia.

De este modo, tu código debería funcionar:

```
seguir = ( primera.equals("s") || primera.equals("S") );
```

Como dice @JackNavaRow, puedes hacer una comparación única convirtiendo el dato a mayúscula.

O, si quieres simplificar, dado que sólo te interesa comparar la primera letra, puedes usar `charAt()`  combinando con `Character.toUpperCase`, en ese cado, sí tienes que usar `==` porque sería una comparación de tipos primitivos (atención aquí al uso de comillas simples para `'S'`:

```
System.out.println("¿Volver a jugar?(si/no): ");
volverjugar = teclado.nextLine();
boolean seguir = Character.toUpperCase(volverjugar.charAt(0))=='S' ;
System.out.println(seguir);
```

O, como ha dicho @x3k_js, puedes recurrir a `equalsIgnoreCase`. En este ejemplo, usamos `charAt` para obtener sólo el primer carácter, lo convertimos a `String` para luego poder hacer una comparación basada en `equalsIgnoreCase`:

```
volverjugar = teclado.nextLine();
String primera = String.valueOf(volverjugar.charAt(0));
boolean seguir=(primera.equalsIgnoreCase("S"));
System.out.println(seguir);
```

Comment: gracias, pero me da en esa tercera linea del charAt "char cannot be converted to String". ¿Debe ser Char primera?

Comment: @alderson puedes declararla del tipo `Character` y funcionará. Revisa el código editado.

Answer (score 7):

```
 System.out.println("¿Volver a jugar? (si/no)");
 String volverjugar = teclado.nextLine(); 

 boolean seguir = false;
 if(volverjugar.startsWith("S") || volverjugar.startsWith("s") ){ 
   seguir = true;
 }
```

Comment: la idea es permitir: SI, si, seguir, Seguir, s (cualquier palabra que comience por la letra "S" o "s").

Comment: Ya lo tienes, solo necesitas saber si contiene la "s" o la "S"

Comment: Con el `contains` compruebas que la palabra contenga la cadena, y esto no es lo que el OP quiere, en todo caso deberías de usar `volverjugar.startsWith("S")` para comprobar que la cadena comience con

Comment: Bien visto,gracias.

Answer (score 5):

lo que pasa es que estas comparando un String con otro  y como dicen los colegas es con equals.

Si queres hacerlo con == podes comparar con char :

```
System.out.println("¿Volver a jugar?(si/no): ");
volverjugar = teclado.nextLine();
char primera=volverjugar.charAt(0); // charAt retorna el chat en la posicion n.
boolean seguir;
seguir = (primera == 's' || primera == 'S'); // Notese las comillas simples.
System.out.println(seguir);
```

Espero que te sirva , abrazo.